# What determines the three Materials gained from completing Alerts?

Tags: control

What determines the three Materials gained from completing Alerts?

Is it "Current Section" + "Next Section"?

Hiss Nodes in **Executive: Communications**: and got two something from Executive and an Astral Blip of the Research Section. Or 2 Threshold Remnants and an Astral Blip.

Kill Key Hiss in **Research: Ritual Division**: House Memory, Threshold Remnant, and Entropic Echo, which from the sections that aren't Research, Investigations, and Foundation.

Or two Blips and an Echo.

Hiss Nodes in **Containment: Transit Corridor North**: 2 House Memories and an Entropic Echo.

I'm wondering if I have to travel to Investigations for its materials to either get them or at least get them in the rotation.